# Extract characters from a string using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column that contains data like:

```
September 12, 2022    
September 15, 2022
December 12, 2022
January 31, 2023
```

and this is what I need from those string:

```
September 2022
September 2022
December 2022
January 2023
```

I only need the month and year of those already existing string values. How can I extract this using sql server?

Kindly help with coming up a solution for this.

I tried using trim but didnt work as expected.

Comment: Storing Date type values as String or Char() types is a real bad idea when you can use the built-in Date / Time types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

The solution, really, is to not store dates as strings; using the right data type means you get automatic validation (avoiding `February 29, 6666` and `who knows what else`), and you get built-in date/time functionality (like extracting just the month name and year) without having to convert or decide what to do with invalid (or null after try_convert) output when the column inevitably gets polluted with garbage.

But if you're stuck with what you're stuck with, as long as you're using English language, you should be able to use convert with style 107:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, x), ' ', YEAR(x))
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, 'September 12, 2022', 107)
  ) AS x(x);
```

So, if you have a table:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, x), ' ', YEAR(x))
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, BadColumnDataType, 107)
    FROM dbo.YourTableName
  ) AS x(x);
```

You may want your code to explicitly say:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MxnK9orQ). And an example of how it *kind of* works in other languages [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/aFBw6-iN).

Answer (score 0):

If your column is using date datatype, you may use this query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(<Your Column Name>, 'MMMM yyyy');
```

However, if you use varchar or nvarchar datatype, you can slightly change this query to:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(<Your Column Name> AS date), 'MMMM yyyy');
```

*FORMAT only works for SQL Server 2012 or later.*

*More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16*